# Ms Access create procedure to insert one row after inserting multiple rows

Tags: ms-access, procedure

I have 3 tables: purchase, purchaseDetails and supplierAccount. When purchase inserted and purchaseDetails are added, one record will be inserted to the supplierAccount based on the sum in purchaseDetails. How to create procedure to add to supplierAccount after inserting multiple rows not at every single row in purchaesDetails table

Answer (score 0):

Well... with the lack of details, this questions could have multiple answers.

But one of the easiest ways to control this is to create a Form that adds the new "purchase" record that has a "Purchase Id" field to link to the other tables.

In this Purchase Form, you can add a subform that links to the "purchaseDetails" table.  You can then add as many records to the subform for each of your line items.  And each of these records will have a Purchase ID that links them back to the Header Purchase record.

Then when you are finished adding these "purchaseDetail" records, you can place a button on your Purchase Form called "Commit" (or something like that) which calls a "Supplier Account Summary" query.

You can then create the "Supplier Account Summary" query to sum up the multiple rows in the "purchaseDetails" table for the records with the current Purchase ID.

After doing so, you might want to create VBA code behind the button to set a "Lock" field so someone can't hit the button multiple times for the same Purchase ID.  This kind of VBA code can get complicated if you want to add more details after the first commit has been done.  You would have to undo a lot stuff and recommit.  Even though the VBA can get very complicated, it's all very do-able.

Anyway, I hope this answers your question.

If you are not using Forms, you just have to create and run the "Supplier Account Summary" query making sure you supply the correct Purchase ID.

Best of luck!